# SOLR MoreLikeThis query

Tags: solr

I want to query my indexed documents via mlt. All of my indexed documents have an id, a cat number and some text.
With the "mlt-query" I want to get all of the documents, which are "similar" to a specified ID. This works very well. But if I want to restrict this search for a special category, it didn't work (please see the URL below):-(

Could anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

```
http://myhost/collection1/mlt?q=id:50fd1dd80364e49234543b3b2807ef+AND+cat:50f05b1506345aa8d&wt=xml&fl=id,text,cat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use filter query with mlt `fq=cat:50f05b1506345aa8d`

e.g.

```
> http://myhost/collection1/mlt?q=id:50fd1dd80364e49234543b3b2807ef&fq=cat:50f05b1506345aa8d&wt=xml&fl=id,text,cat
```